# Implementing Row Expansion in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, datagrid, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I recently transitioned from .NET 4.7 to .NET MAUI and now I'm faced with the task of displaying a DataGrid on the UI. The requirement is to have additional DataGrid expand below a row when the user clicks on it. In .NET 4.7, I accomplished this using DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate and successfully implemented a 4-layer nested DataGrid with this feature.

However, I discovered that .NET MAUI does not have a built-in DataGrid control. As a workaround, I am currently utilizing the SyncFusion DataGrid in my project. My question is: Is there a way to replicate the same behavior, i.e., expanding row details, using the SyncFusion DataGrid or any other solution within the context of .NET MAUI?

Comment: Without building the feature yourself or waiting until it's added, it's unlikely. MAUI is still missing a lot of features from Windows Forms and has slowly been receiving updates but isn't quite where it needs to be for certain functionality.